# quarz cron expression to run a job every n weeks on mon, wed?

Tags: quartz-scheduler, crontrigger

I have a (weird) requirement to schedule a job for every n weeks on Mon, Wed at 9 AM.
The trigger must be Quartz compatible.

Here is how it will look like when n=2.

> July 3rd 2017 (Mon)
>
> July 5rd 2017 (Wed)
>
> July 17th 2017 (Mon)
>
> July 19th 2017(Wed)
>
> July 31st 2017(Mon)
>
> Aug 2nd 2017(Wed)
>
> and so-on..

what I could get so far is

`0 0 9 * * MON,WED` - but this is for every week. I cant build a cron expression for every 2 weeks.

I also looked at Quartz [DateIntervalTrigger](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/previous_versions/1.8.5/org/quartz/DateIntervalTrigger.html) where I can give interval Unit of 2. but I still can't get the functionality of MON **AND** WED in it.

I am open to other Quartz triggers. but I can't find that will satisfy my needs here.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is achievable with a single Quartz trigger.

If it is not a problem, you can satisfy your scheduling requirements with two  [CalendarIntervalTriggers](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/CalendarIntervalTrigger.html) with the following properties:

**Trigger for Mondays**

[image: Trigger for Mondays]

**Trigger for Wednesdays**

[image: Trigger for Wednesdays]

**Resulting job fire times**

[image: Final job fire times]

Screenshots are from [QuartzDesk](https://www.quartzdesk.com), a Quartz scheduler management and monitoring product that I founded. Obviously you do not have to use QuartzDesk to create the above-described triggers, it just made it easier to present the idea.

Comment: thanks for suggestions. I already thought about this idea. but wondering if it is possible with a single trigger